# How to imitate Contacts of Android/IOS using Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I need to create an activity similar to how the Contacts are displayed.  Instead of showing the contacts, I need to show data coming from a SQLite table.  I also need to have the data divided alphabetically.  The navigator in the right side with the search is also needed.  What widgets or layout must I use to implement/imitate such interface?

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK documentation provides documentation on how to achieve such a type of List, by implementing a [SectionIndexer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) in your [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).

There is also a complete sample of how to implement such a ListView in the [Mono for Android Samples repository](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/LabelledSections)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this
[section indexer in android](http://www.motzwrit.es/post/18090937895/listview-fastscroll-with-sectionindexer-in-mono-for)